# Arduino LCD game not displaying

Tags: c++, arduino, lcd

I am getting crazy on my Snake LCD game. 
I use an Arduino Mega and I'd like to use the LCD screen and the PmodKYPD for my Snake game. The problem is that it will not display anything, no matter which key I will press.
Here is my code:

```
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include "Keypad.h"

byte mySnake[8][8] =
{
{ B00000,
  B00000,
  B00011,
  B00110,
  B01100,
  B11000,
  B00000,
},
{ B00000,
  B11000,
  B11110,
  B00011,
  B00001,
  B00000,
  B00000,
},
{ B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B11111,
  B01110,
},
{ B00000,
  B00000,
  B00011,
  B01111,
  B11000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
},
{ B00000,
  B11100,
  B11111,
  B00001,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
},
{ B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B11000,
  B01101,
  B00111,
  B00000,
},
{ B00000,
  B00000,
  B01110,
  B11011,
  B11111,
  B01110,
  B00000,
},
{ B00000,
  B00000,
  B00000,
  B01000,
  B10000,
  B01000,
  B00000,
}
};
 // keypad type definition
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] =
 {{'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'0','F','E','D'}};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {
  37, 36, 35, 34}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {
  33,32, 31, 30}; // connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

boolean levelz[5][2][16] = {
{{false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
{false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false}},

{{true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true},
{true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true}},

{{true,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,true},
{true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,true}},

{{true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,true,false,false},
{false,false,false,false,true,false,false,true,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,true}}
};

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2); 
unsigned long time, timeNow;
int gameSpeed;
boolean skip, gameOver, gameStarted;
int olddir;
int selectedLevel,levels;

int NUM_KEYS = 5;
int adc_key_in;
int key=-1;
char key_read;
int oldkey=-1;

boolean x[16][80];
byte myChar[8];
byte nullChar[8] = { 0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x0 };
boolean special;

struct partdef
{
  int row,column,dir; //0 - up, 1 - down, 2 - right, 3 - left
  struct partdef *next;
};
typedef partdef part;

part *head, *tail;
int i,j,collected;
long pc,pr;

void drawMatrix()
{
  int cc=0;
  if (!gameOver)
  {
  x[pr][pc] = true;
  //for (i=0;i<8;i++) lcd.createChar(i, nullChar);
  for(int r=0;r<2;r++)
  {
    for(int c=0;c<16;c++)
    {
      special = false;
      for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
      {
        byte b=B00000;
        if (x[r*8+i][c*5+0]) {b+=B10000; special = true;}
        if (x[r*8+i][c*5+1]) {b+=B01000; special = true;}
        if (x[r*8+i][c*5+2]) {b+=B00100; special = true;}
        if (x[r*8+i][c*5+3]) {b+=B00010; special = true;}
        if (x[r*8+i][c*5+4]) {b+=B00001; special = true;}
        myChar[i] = b;
      }
      if (special)
      {
        lcd.createChar(cc, myChar);
        lcd.setCursor(c,r);
        lcd.write(byte(cc));
        cc++;
      }
      else
      {
        lcd.setCursor(c,r);
        if (levelz[selectedLevel][r][c]) lcd.write(255);
        else lcd.write(254);
      }
    }
  }
  }
}

void freeList()
{
  part *p,*q;
  p = tail;
  while (p!=NULL)
  {
    q = p;
    p = p->next;
    free(q);
  }
  head = tail = NULL;
}

void gameOverFunction()
{
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  freeList();
  lcd.setCursor(3,0);
  lcd.print("Game Over!");
  lcd.setCursor(4,1);
  lcd.print("Score: ");
  lcd.print(collected);
  delay(1000);
}

void growSnake()
{
  part *p;
  p = (part*)malloc(sizeof(part));
  p->row = tail->row;
  p->column = tail->column;
  p->dir = tail->dir;
  p->next = tail;
  tail = p;
}

void newPoint()
{

  part *p;
  p = tail;
  boolean newp = true;
  while (newp)
  {
    pr = random(16);
    pc = random(80);
    newp = false;
    if (levelz[selectedLevel][pr / 8][pc / 5]) newp=true;
    while (p->next != NULL && !newp)
    {
      if (p->row == pr && p->column == pc) newp = true;
      p = p->next;
    }
  }

  if (collected < 13 && gameStarted) growSnake();
}

void moveHead()
{
  switch(head->dir) // 1 step in direction
  {
    case 0: head->row--; break;
    case 1: head->row++; break;
    case 2: head->column++; break;
    case 3: head->column--; break;
    default : break;
  }
  if (head->column >= 80) head->column = 0;
  if (head->column < 0) head->column = 79;
  if (head->row >= 16) head->row = 0;
  if (head->row < 0) head->row = 15;

  if (levelz[selectedLevel][head->row / 8][head->column / 5]) gameOver = true; // wall collision check

  part *p;
  p = tail;
  while (p != head && !gameOver) // self collision
  {
    if (p->row == head->row && p->column == head->column) gameOver = true;
    p = p->next;
  }
  if (gameOver)
    gameOverFunction();
  else
  {
  x[head->row][head->column] = true;

  if (head->row == pr && head->column == pc) // point pickup check
  {
    collected++;
    if (gameSpeed < 25) gameSpeed+=3;
    newPoint();
  }
  }
}

void moveAll()
{
  part *p;
  p = tail;
  x[p->row][p->column] = false;
  while (p->next != NULL)
  {
    p->row = p->next->row;
    p->column = p->next->column;
    p->dir = p->next->dir;
    p = p->next;
  }
  moveHead();
}

void createSnake(int n) // n = size of snake
{
  for (i=0;i<16;i++)
    for (j=0;j<80;j++)
      x[i][j] = false;

  part *p, *q;
  tail = (part*)malloc(sizeof(part));
  tail->row = 7;
  tail->column = 39 + n/2;
  tail->dir = 3;
  q = tail;
  x[tail->row][tail->column] = true;
  for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) // build snake from tail to head
  {
    p = (part*)malloc(sizeof(part));
    p->row = q->row;
    p->column = q->column - 1; //initial snake id placed horizoltally
    x[p->row][p->column] = true;
    p->dir = q->dir;
    q->next = p;
    q = p;
  }
  if (n>1)
  {
    p->next = NULL;
    head  = p;
  }
  else
  {
    tail->next = NULL;
    head = tail;
  }
}

void startF()
{
  gameOver = false;
  gameStarted = false;
  selectedLevel = 1;

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Select level: 1");
  for(i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
    lcd.createChar(i,mySnake[i]);
    lcd.setCursor(i+4,1);
    lcd.write(byte(i));
  }
  collected = 0;
  gameSpeed = 8;
  createSnake(3);
  time = 0;
}
void setup()
{
  levels = 5; //number of lvls
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  startF();
}

void loop()
{
  if (!gameOver && !gameStarted)
  {
   key_read = keypad.getKey();  // get key press
   key = key_read - '0';
   if (key != oldkey)   // if keypress is detected
   {
      delay(50);  // wait for debounce time
      key_read = keypad.getKey();  // get key press
      key = key_read - '0';
     if (key != oldkey)    
     {  
       oldkey = key;
       if (key >=0)
       {
         olddir = head->dir;
         if (key==1 && selectedLevel<levels) selectedLevel++;
         if (key==2 && selectedLevel>1) selectedLevel--;
         if (key==4)
         {
           lcd.clear();
           selectedLevel--;
           newPoint();
           gameStarted = true;
         }
         else
         {
           lcd.setCursor(14,0);
           lcd.print(selectedLevel);
         }
       }
     }
   }
  }
  if (!gameOver && gameStarted)
  {
   skip = false; //skip the second moveAll() function call if the first was made

   key_read = keypad.getKey();  // get key press
   key = key_read - '0';
   if (key != oldkey)   // if keypress is detected
   {
     delay(50);  // wait for debounce time
      key_read = keypad.getKey();  // get key press
      key = key_read - '0';
     if (key != oldkey)    
     {  
       oldkey = key;
       if (key >=0)
       {
         olddir = head->dir;
         if (key==0 && head->dir!=3) head->dir = 2;
         if (key==1 && head->dir!=1) head->dir = 0;
         if (key==2 && head->dir!=0) head->dir = 1;
         if (key==3 && head->dir!=2) head->dir = 3;

         if (olddir != head->dir)
         {
           skip = true;
           delay(1000/gameSpeed);
           moveAll();
           drawMatrix();
         }
       }
     }
   }
   if (!skip)
   {
     timeNow = millis();
     if (timeNow - time > 1000 / gameSpeed)
     {
       moveAll();
       drawMatrix();
       time = millis();
     }
   }
  }
  if(gameOver)
  {

    key_read = keypad.getKey();  // get key press
    key = key_read - '0';
   if (key != oldkey)   // if keypress is detected
   {
     delay(50);  // wait for debounce time
      key_read = keypad.getKey();  // get key press
      key = key_read - '0';
     if (key != oldkey)    
     {  
       oldkey = key;
       if (key >=0)
       {
          startF();
       }
     }
   }

  }
}
```

Does anyone know something about this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the **full** *source code*. What is the value of `gameSpeed`? what does `drawMatrix()` do?

Comment: I just edited it. I thought the problem was with the way I use the keypad because mySnake is being dispayed but when I press a key nothing changes...

Comment: This is not a 'debug my code for free service'. Please debug your code and come back with a minimal example which reproduces whatever problem you're experiencing. Do not dump your tons-of-code at our faces!

Comment: @Ela that's easy to find out: replace key input with a function generating random key presses and see whether it works or not.

Comment: @Ela: I upvoted, but **after you found and corrected** the error and get **working code**, please share it on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some feedback on how to do things :)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin thank you. I will share it, in case I would find the error...I thought at something similar before and I set a fixed value for key but I couldn't find the bug and I have just 2 hours per week for testing this code on Arduino Mega.

Comment: yes, but what happens if you fix the value of *key*? it moves? it doesn't?

Comment: **mySnake** ramains displayed on the LCD screen.